# How to show/hide fields on link click?

Tags: php, laravel, navigation, laravel-blade

I am using laravel 5.3
I have a responding navigation menu, when I click on domains, it shows all the domains I already have in DB, and then when I click on one of these domains I get the corresponding projects.

Now, I am want that when I click on project it displays all the corresponding data in a table for example. But, this is what I am getting :

[image]

this is ProjectController :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $projects1=DB::table('projects')->where('domain_id', '=', 1)->get();
  $projects2=DB::table('projects')->where('domain_id', '=', 2)->get();
  $projects3=DB::table('projects')->where('domain_id', '=', 3)->get();

  return view('projects.index',compact('projects', 'projects1', 'projects2', 'projects3'));
}
```

and this is index.blade.php :

```
<div class="nav-side-menu">
  <div class="brand">Menu</div>
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
  <div class="menu-list">
    <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">           
      <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Domains <span class="arrow"></span>  </a>
      </li>
      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
        <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#domain1_projet" class="collapsed active">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Domain 1 <span class="arrow"></span></a>
        </li>
        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="domain1_projet">
           @foreach ($projects1 as $key => $project)
             <li><a href="#">{{$project->title}}</a></li>                    
           @endforeach
           <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
             <th>No</th>
             <th>title</th>
             <th>code</th>
             <th>domain_id</th>  
            </tr>
            @foreach ($projects1 as $key => $project1)
             <tr>
              <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
              <td>{{ $project1->title }}</td>
              <td>{{ $project1->code }}</td> 
              <td>{{ $project1->domain_id}}</td>
             </tr>
           @endforeach
          </table>
         </ul>                             
         <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#domain2_projet" class="collapsed active">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Domain 2 <span class="arrow"></span></a>
         </li>
         <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="domaine2_projet">
           @foreach ($projects2 as $key => $project)
            <li><a href="#">{{$project->title}}</a></li>                    
           @endforeach                    
         </ul>                  
       </ul>
     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

the @if clause I added before table was just to test, but I need to change that. I want to be able to display data of each project not in a manual way. I also want to know how to show and hide the information of each project when clicking on the links. 
As you can see in `index.blade.php`, It's because I already know the names of project I did `if (($project->intitule)=="Title")` and `elseif(($project->intitule)=="Project2")` But, in fact I have many projects in database. How can I be able to display all the projects and then when I click on one of them, how can get a table containing information of that specific project

Comment: If you want click on specific project id and show the information about this project "Without refresh the page" you can use AJAX. Otherwise if you want only show all data try to insert a loop foreach inside other loop foreach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
  $projects=DB::table('projects')->get();
  return view('projects.index',compact('projects'));
}
```

**VIEW**

```
<div class="nav-side-menu">
  <div class="brand">Menu</div>
  <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x toggle-btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu-content"></i>
  <div class="menu-list">
    <ul id="menu-content" class="menu-content collapse out">           
      <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#products" class="collapsed active">
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Domains <span class="arrow"></span>  </a>
      </li>


      <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="products">
        @for ($i = 0; $i < count($projects); $i++)
        <li  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#domain1_projet{{$i}}" class="collapsed active">
          <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gift fa-lg"></i> Domain {{$projects[$i]->domain_id}} <span class="arrow"></span></a>
        </li>


        <ul class="sub-menu collapse" id="domain1_projet{{$i}}">

             <li><a href="#">{{$projects[$i]->title}}</a></li>                    

           <table class="table table-bordered">
            <tr>
             <th>No</th>
             <th>title</th>
             <th>code</th>
             <th>domain_id</th>  
            </tr>

             <tr>
              <td>{{ $i }}</td>
              <td>{{ $projects[$i]->title }}</td>
              <td>{{ $projects[$i]->code }}</td> 
              <td>{{ $projects[$i]->domain_id}}</td>
             </tr>

          </table>
        </ul>                             
        @endfor



       </ul>


     </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Try it! and let me know if return errors!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this, but, I am getting this error :

ErrorException in Collection.php line 1320:
Undefined offset: 4 (View: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-16.1\eds-www\PC\resources\views\projects\index.blade.php)

Comment: try this, how many results it return? $test = count($projects);

Comment: where should I add this please ?

Comment: controller. before the return the view

Comment: return $test = count($projects);

Comment: try to change: @for ($i = 0; $i < count($projects); $i++), i updated my answer

Comment: This is working ! Still have one problem. each domain may have multiple projects, but, it only shows one project by domain

Comment: it show one because you have "domain_id" inside your table "projects", if you want do a relationship where each project can have more one domain you need create a new table "domains" with relation "project_id". so you will need change migrations, models, and change loop for blade. But this is other question, just create new question in stackoverflow,

Comment: you misunderstood me, domain can have multiple projects. But, project, has only One domain.

Comment: i get it, so you must do the loop with table "domains" and not with "projects"

Comment: the more easy way is show all domains list with normal loop foreach and when you click in some domain you can redirect to other view with all project related.